# SQL Server Deadlock Graph - Table, Page or Row Lock?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

Is there any way to decipher if a lock in a deadlock graph is Table, Page or Row level? I have all the information I need from the graph, including the Isolation Level, (2) but I really want to know this, too.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the deadlock graph XML you will see something like:

```
<deadlock-list>
  <deadlock victim="...">
    <process-list>
      <process id="..." ... waitresource="X:..."
...
```

The `X` is the interesting bit, possible values you are interested in are:

- `RID` for row id (row level locking)
- `PAG` for page level lock
- `OBJECT` (which may be further qualified `TAB` indicating a table lock)

There are a few others kinds listed in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) also.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Although in my graph I have 2 processes, which appear to be using different pages:

waitresource="RID: 21:1:2588:0"
waitresource="RID: 21:1:2699:1"

So if they are using different pages, then they can't be conflicting over the same row, correct? Because I'm using a WITH (ROWLOCK) hint on this query.

Comment: If process 1 is holding 2699 and wants 2588, and process 2 is holding 2588 and wants 2699, that would deadlock. Remember a deadlock implies a circular dependency.